Firebase IEnumerator crashes Unity
i'm trying to retrieve data from firebase, but even if ienumerator isn't get executed, unity crashes, so it have 50/50 chance of crash, it can crash, it can not crash.
Unity: 2022.3.34f1
Windows 10.
IEnumerator code here:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Database;

public class ScratchID : MonoBehaviour
{
    DatabaseReference dbref;
    public InputField Login;
    public InputField Password;
    void Start()
    {
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }
    public IEnumerator LogIn()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Login.text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password.text))
        {
            var login = dbref.Child("users").GetValueAsync();
            yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => login.IsCompleted);
            DataSnapshot snapshot = login.Result;
            if(snapshot.Exists)
            {
                if(snapshot.Child(Login.text).Value.ToString() != null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Account is already exists!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void ExecuteLogIn()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LogIn());
    }
}

Editor.log:
https://pastebin.com/XNKBHTMY
